# Excel inserted function does not automaticly work

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function, vba

I insert a formula via vba:

```
Range("B6").Formula = "=SUMMENPRODUKT(TEILERGEBNIS(109,INDIREKT(""Daten!I""&ZEILE($2:$238)))*((Tabelle1[Artikel]=""10F0553s"") + (Tabelle1[Artikel]=""10F0553""))*(Tabelle1[Fertig]<>1))"
```

This works fine, but the formula returns #Name.

But if I click on the cell and just press ENTER it returns the right value.

Autocalculation is set to "on" in excel.

Comment: just click on the cell, then go to Formula - evaluate, there you can see which part of the formula gives the error.

Comment: Yes, but the formula has actually no error. If I just refresh the cell it works. I can also save the file, close it and open it again and the cell works.

Comment: This was my best guess trying to find the solution. Please post where it finds error (if at all).

Comment: It say, the formular contains text which could not be interprated. But yeah if I click on the cell an press enter it works fine.

Comment: "But yeah if I click on the cell an press enter it works fine." - I know, you've written it three times already. Are you happy with that or would like to have a solution?

Comment: Does inserting the same formula manually work?

Comment: Inserting the same formula works fine. I would be also happy if the enter gets done automaticly ^^

Comment: ""Daten!I""&ZEILE($2:$238)   I think the problem is somehow this row. At the moment of the creation, Excel dont know there to read ZEILE() from. (In english the function is called something like ROW()).

Comment: What about putting a command to recalculate (`Application.Calculate`) on the next line? That will tell the sheet to recalculate as if you press Enter.

Comment: Excel vba is american English centric.  In that when using `.Formula` the formulas must be in English.  So try one of two things: either translate the formula into English or use `.FormulaLocal` instead.

Comment: FormulaLocal doens´t work, return runtime error 1004.  Application.Calculate does not make any change.

Comment: Then try translating all the formulas into English SUMPRODUCT,SUBTOTAL,INDIRECT,ROW

Comment: @ScottCraner ty very much solved the problem